# Does AWS EKS provides a DNS wildcard CNAME that will point to all Kubernetes active worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, eks

Usually, when i use a managed Kubernetes from various clouds, once i create a managed Kubernetes cluster, i am given a DNS wildcard CNAME such as `*.536642b.nodes.k8s.fr-par.scw.cloud` that will automatically contain all the active Kubernetes worker nodes.

Does AWS EKS provides such a wildcard CNAME ?

This is very useful when not using a load balancer, but rather using an ingress in HostNetwork mode, such as Traefik for example.
Il would simply create my own wildcard CNAME in my domain pointing to the wildcard CNAME provides, and create ingress resources for my apps in K8s, and ... well, you get the point

I have searched in vain in AWS docs about it. All i could find was "ExternalDNS" which i am not sure if it is about the same need, and more over it had to be added manually

Comment: Certainly not, because Nodes traditionally don't have public ip addresses in order for such a CNAME to make any sense. The way EKS exposes cluster services is through ELBs

Comment: ok then, i will configure Traefik to setup a service type of `loadbalancer` then.

Note that currently, my EKS test cluster created with AWS CLI tools does create EC2 worker nodes with public IP addresses. The associated security group does not allow access by default, but nevertheless, public IP addresses are assigned to instances